# Не удается использовать объект DependencyObject, принадлежащий к другому потоку, отличному от его родительского объекта Freezable

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, barcode

есть часть кода такая, тут идет печать на принтер. Использую wpf, прочитал что возможно но все равно валится ошибка, в чем может быть проблема? И возможно использую что-то лишнее. Подскажите как можно исправить?

```
    GeneratedBarcode MyBarCodeBarcodeWriter = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode($"{(char)0x00F1}(01){gtin}(11){dateStart}(17){expirationDate}(10)10(21){partNum} ", BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128).SaveAsJpeg("C:/gs1code128.jpg");
            MyBarCodeBarcodeWriter.ResizeTo(300, 30);
            MyBarCodeBarcodeWriter.ToBitmap();
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:/gs1code128.jpg");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
            MemoryStream bufferPasser = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = bufferPasser;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            ImageBrush myImageBrush = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
                myCanvas.Background = myImageBrush;
                myCanvas.Height = 50;
                myCanvas.Width = 300;
                PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
                printDialog.PrintVisual(myCanvas, "Распечатываем элемент Canvas");

            });
```

`Не удается использовать объект DependencyObject, принадлежащий к другому потоку, отличному от его родительского объекта Freezable.`

Comment: `new BitmapImage();` нужно вызывать в UI потоке. И непонятно, зачем эти пляски с преобразованием JPG в PNG

Comment: Почему сразу нельзя `bitmap.StreamSource = File.OpenRead("C:/gs1code128.jpg")`? И что за класс `BarcodeWriter`, почему вы сохраняете на диск это все? Он не может сохранить в память? Что за библиотека, где ее документация?

Comment: Какя версия дотнета?

Comment: 4.8 фреймворк использую

Comment: вот документация на BarcodeWriter https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/troubleshooting/gs1-128/

Comment: А в плане ui потоке? Потому что только начинаю разбираться с c#

Comment: `4.8 фреймворк использую` ууу, это что-то древнее, вряд-ли чем-то смогу помочь. Еще и пакет платный. Ща попробую в доках покопаться.

Comment: 4.8 это самый последний фреймворк) .Net framework 4.8

Comment: Самый последний фреймворк - это .NET 6

Comment: Ну среда да, у меня .Net 6

Comment: Так что, как решить данную проблему возможно?

Comment: `Ну среда да, у меня .Net 6` Framework 4.8 и .NET 6 - это 2 большие несовместимые разницы, у вас либо то, либо другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопался в [доках](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/object-reference/api/IronBarCode.GeneratedBarcode.html) IronBarCode. Много ошибок допускаете, и много лишнего делаете.

```
string input = $"{(char)0x00F1}(01){gtin}(11){dateStart}(17){expirationDate}(10)10(21){partNum}";
GeneratedBarcode barcode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(input, BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128).ResizeTo(300, 30);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Stream stream = barcode.ToWindowsBitmapStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
    }
    ms.Position = 0;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.PrintVisual(img, "Распечатываем элемент Image");
    });
}
```

Comment: появляется ошибка Вызвано исключение: "System.NotSupportedException" в mscorlib.dll

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что если использовать данный код(представленный мною) то все нормально и все печатается, но в том случае если я его использую в главном окне, он мне пишет ошибки.

Comment: @AlexSuspect обновил код в ответе.

Comment: Да спасибо большое. Разобрался. Ваш ответ помог мне!

Comment: @aeport Стала появляться ошибка "Доступ к закрытому потоку невозможен." на строке using 
(Stream stream = barcode.ToWindowsBitmapStream())

Comment: @AlexSuspect что, полмесяца до этого она не появлялась и все работало? Закрытый поток, это который уже кто-то закрыл ранее, либо через `Close()` либо через `using`. Один тот же поток открыть дважды не получится, ошибка в коде. Если у вас новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, покажите там код.